# Javascript & Django Channels: Chat app sign off notification on window close

Tags: javascript, python, django, chat, django-channels

I am writing a chat app with Javascript and Django Channels.  I am trying get a "User has left chat." message to send when the window is closed, maybe also when the websocket is closed.  I'm not sure if the websocket is closing too quickly, but the code as I have it currently is not working.  It's possible I should be defining within the disconnect function in the chat consumer. I'm not sure of the order some of this stuff is handled in.

Javascript

```
// Declare variables
    var userName;
    var currentZone = new Date().toTimeString().slice(17);
    // var roomName = {{ room_name_json }};
    document.getElementById("chatname").innerHTML = roomName;

// Create Websocket
    var chatSocket = new ReconnectingWebSocket(
        'ws://' + window.location.host +
        '/ws/chat/' + roomName + '/');

// Send message
    chatSocket.onmessage = function(e) {
        var data = JSON.parse(e.data);
        var message = data['message'];
        document.querySelector('#chat-log').value += (message + '\n');
        document.getElementById("chat-log").scrollTop = document.getElementById("chat-log").scrollHeight;
    };

// Set User
    window.onload = function(){
        userName = sessionStorage.getItem("user");
        if (userName==null || userName===false) {
            userName = prompt("Please enter a username:");
        };
        return userName;
    }

//Join message
    function chatJoin() {
        if(chatSocket.readyState == false) {
           window.setTimeout(chatJoin, 500); /* Wait 500 milliseconds*/
        } else {
            var message = userName + " has joined the chat."
            chatSocket.send(JSON.stringify({
                'message': message
            }));
        }
    }
    chatJoin();

    // chatSocket.onclose = function(e) {
    //     console.error('Chat socket closed unexpectedly');
    // };

// Sign off message
    window.unload = function(e) {
        var message = userName +"has left the chat."
        chatSocket.send(JSON.stringify({
            'message': message
        }));
    };

    document.querySelector('#chat-message-input').focus();
    document.querySelector('#chat-message-input').onkeyup = function(e) {
        if (e.keyCode === 13) {  // enter, return
            document.querySelector('#chat-message-submit').click();
        }
    };

    document.querySelector('#chat-message-submit').onclick = function(e) {
        var currentDate = new Date();
        var currentTime = currentDate.toLocaleTimeString();
        var messageInputDom = document.querySelector('#chat-message-input');
        var message = userName + " " + currentTime + currentZone + ': ' + messageInputDom.value;
        chatSocket.send(JSON.stringify({
            'message': message
        }));

        messageInputDom.value = '';
    };
```

Consumer

```
from channels.generic.websocket import AsyncWebsocketConsumer
from channels.generic.websocket import WebsocketConsumer

import json

class ChatConsumer(AsyncWebsocketConsumer):
    async def connect(self):
        self.room_name = self.scope['url_route']['kwargs']['room_name']
        self.room_group_name = 'chat_%s' % self.room_name

        # Join room group
        await self.channel_layer.group_add(
            self.room_group_name,
            self.channel_name
        )

        await self.accept()

    async def disconnect(self, close_code):
        # Leave room group
        await self.channel_layer.group_discard(
            self.room_group_name,
            self.channel_name
        )

    # Receive message from WebSocket
    async def receive(self, text_data):
        text_data_json = json.loads(text_data)
        message = text_data_json['message']

        # Send message to room group
        await self.channel_layer.group_send(
            self.room_group_name,
            {
                'type': 'chat_message',
                'message': message
            }
        )

    # Receive message from room group
    async def chat_message(self, event):
        message = event['message']

        # Send message to WebSocket
        await self.send(text_data=json.dumps({
            'message': message
        }))
```

I have also tried the disconnect function like this, I'd like to include the username in the message so it would need to receive some data:

```
    async def disconnect(self, text_data, close_code):
        text_data_json = json.loads(text_data)
        message = text_data_json['message']

        # Send message to room group
        await self.channel_layer.group_send(
            self.room_group_name,
            {
                'type': 'chat_message',
                'message': message
            }
        )

        # Leave room group
        await self.channel_layer.group_discard(
            self.room_group_name,
            self.channel_name
        )
```

Comment: You don't need to change the signature of the disconnect function since it's a hook that you're not calling yourself. Each consumer connection has context information stored in the scope. If you're using the authentication approach used in the docs then you can get the user from self.scop['user'] and then fetch the username from the user. You could store any other context info in the scope a in connect and make it accessible to other methods

Comment: Thanks for this.  I did not use authentication because I was trying to build the project without a backend.  The userName variable is a var set with JavaScript and stored in session.  I have found that setting a var like self.user_name works globally making it available to my disconnect function.  Do you know of a way I could send the JavaScript var over the websocket? I've tried sending it as JSON a few ways with .send().  A test setting self.user_name to text_data_json['message'] was not successful in the current receive() function.  I need a way to get the var, but don't need to send it.

Comment: I see the issue with this, since consumers are backend code they are not isolated to users, passing the user var in will only preserve the most recent user that joined.  Do you have advice on simple ways to implement authentication?  The only thing I am looking to preserve is usernames paired with the appropriate session.  Is there any way to cache this information in the python code without implementing a database?

Comment: The docs show how to use the in-built session authentication here https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/authentication.html.
As for consumers, each instance is for a separate connection so you can store values in the consumer object that are for a particular user. That is the essence of the self.scope. Just like normal django views have request.user. You can also pass the username as a querystring when initiating the websocket connection. The value can be accessed in self.scope

Comment: You can post a separate question for that with more details

Answer (score 0):

Instead of sending "user has disconnected" message from the disconnecting client, let the server do it.

So, on `disconnect`, before discarding the group, send `XXX has left the chat.` message.

Comment: This is the approach I considered.  Do you know how I could pass data to the disconnect function?  It looks like disconnect functions cannot receive data? https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/consumers.html 

I'll re-add the details of what I tired to the question, I took it out when I noted the issue that disconnect doesn't accept a text_data argument.